# Getting hard-drive serial number on Windows

Tags: c++, c++17, windows, winapi, com

The point is to get the serial number of one of the hard drives on Windows. My code is based on [an example from MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/example--getting-wmi-data-from-the-local-computer). I tried to make it an exception-safe, self-contained function. It works, to the best of my knowledge. All comments are welcome, especially about correctness, exception safety and performance issues.

```
#define _WIN32_DCOM
#include <Wbemidl.h>
#include <comdef.h>

#include <memory>
#include <optional>
#include <string_view>

#pragma comment(lib, "wbemuuid.lib")

namespace ComWrappers {
    struct ComDeleter final {
        template <class T>
        auto operator()(T* const p) const noexcept -> void {
            if (p) p->Release();
        }
    };

    template <class T>
    using ComPtr = ::std::unique_ptr<T, ComDeleter>;

    struct ComInit final {
    private:
        bool _succeeded;

    public:
        ComInit() noexcept
            : _succeeded{ SUCCEEDED(::CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_MULTITHREADED)) }
        {}

        [[nodiscard]] operator bool() const noexcept { return _succeeded; }

        ~ComInit() noexcept {
            if (_succeeded) ::CoUninitialize();
        }
    };
}  // namespace ComWrappers

[[nodiscard]] auto GetHardDriveSerialNumber() noexcept -> ::std::optional<::std::wstring> {
    using namespace ::ComWrappers;

    // Initialize COM
    ComInit comOwner;
    if (!comOwner) return ::std::nullopt;

    // locator to WMI
    ComPtr<::IWbemLocator> loc = nullptr;
    {
        ::IWbemLocator* pLoc = nullptr;
        auto const hres =
            ::CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WbemLocator, 0, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                IID_IWbemLocator, reinterpret_cast<LPVOID*>(&pLoc));

        if (FAILED(hres)) return ::std::nullopt;
        loc.reset(pLoc);
    }

    ComPtr<::IWbemServices> svc = nullptr;
    {  // Connect to WMI
        ::IWbemServices* pSvc = nullptr;
        auto const hres = loc->ConnectServer(
            _bstr_t(L"ROOT\\CIMV2"), 
            nullptr, nullptr, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            &pSvc
        );
        if (FAILED(hres)) return ::std::nullopt;
        svc.reset(pSvc);
    }

    {  // Set security levels
        auto const hres = ::CoSetProxyBlanket(
                svc.get(),     
                RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT,             
                RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE,              
                nullptr,                       
                RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL,        
                RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,   
                nullptr,                       
                EOAC_NONE                      
            );

        if (FAILED(hres)) return ::std::nullopt;
    }

    ComPtr<::IEnumWbemClassObject> enumerator = nullptr;
    {  // Make requests of WMI
        ::IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = nullptr;
        auto const hres = svc->ExecQuery(
            bstr_t("WQL"), bstr_t("SELECT SerialNumber FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia"),
            WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, nullptr,
            &pEnumerator);

        if (FAILED(hres)) return ::std::nullopt;
        enumerator.reset(pEnumerator);
    }

    ::std::optional<::std::wstring> result = ::std::nullopt;

    // Get the data
    while (true) {
        ComPtr<::IWbemClassObject> clsObj = nullptr;
        {
            ::IWbemClassObject* pclsObj = nullptr;
            ULONG uReturn = 0;
            auto const hres = enumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &pclsObj, &uReturn);

            if (FAILED(hres) || uReturn == 0) break;
            clsObj.reset(pclsObj);
        }

        VARIANT vtProp{};

        // Get serial number
        auto const hres = clsObj->Get(L"SerialNumber", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);

        if (FAILED(hres)) continue;

        // RAII for variant class
        struct VariantOwner {
            VARIANT* v;
            ~VariantOwner() noexcept {
                ::VariantClear(v);
            }
        } variantOwner{ &vtProp };

        // can't allow empty strings
        if (*vtProp.bstrVal == '\0') continue;

        try {
            result = vtProp.bstrVal;
        }
        catch (...) {
            // no need to do anything as
            // a failure would return the default 'nullopt'
        }
        break;
    }

    return result;
}


// Example test driver

#include <iostream>

auto main() -> int {
    auto const hid = GetHardDriveSerialNumber();
    if (hid) ::std::wcout << *hid << '\n';
    else ::std::wcout << "Failed to get serial number\n";
}
```

Comment: good show using `std::unique_ptr` for COM.  I've found that most people have not stumbled onto that trick.  Good adding RAII to COM VARIENT, but shouldn't that be part of the `COM_wrappers` namespace and library?

Comment: What if the thread you call this on is already activated into some kind of COM apartment that's not necessarily a Multithreaded apartment?

Comment: @JDługosz The `VariantOwner` class should only call `VariantClear` if `clsObj->Get` succeeds. For that reason, it's a bit too specialized and I didn't want to put to the general namespace.

Comment: @JDługosz I am not sure about your second comment. Do you recommend I check for `RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE`?

Comment: What I've done is create my own thread that wasn't used already by the caller.  I don't recall a CHANGED_MODE ... just an error if it was already set up, and maybe a count if it's called more than once in a compatible way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (FAILED(hres)) return ::std::nullopt;
svc.reset(pSvc);
```

It bothers me that this is repeated, and more generally, you need boilerplate to *use* one of the COM Wrappers.  Ideally, `&svc` would return the thing that the COM calls actually wanted.  Since you are not making a special COM wrapper but relying on `unique_ptr` you can instead make a non-member function that's *not* called `operator&`.  So:

```
loc->ConnectServer(
    _bstr_t(L"ROOT\\CIMV2"), 
    nullptr, nullptr, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    COM(svc) //  no separate "plain" variable
    );
```

You would not need a separate plain pointer that needs to be `reset` into the variable you really wanted.  You could rely on this still being `nullptr` on failure, without having to check the `HRESULT`, in cases where you were not diagnosing the issue.

Generally, though, turn the `HRESULT` into an `error_code`, with a common function.  I have some memory that, in the past anyway, MSVC++ did not have a fully fleshed out `error_category` for Windows errors, but Boost did.  I don't know if that's still the case, but I want to point out that this is available, complete with the error text look up.

You could have the helper I called `COM` here simply return the address of the underying pointer directly, or it could return a proxy that has both an `operator T**` *and* an `operator void**` so you don't need the cast in the `CoCreateInstance` call.

Comment: I don't think your `COM` function would work since we don't have a reference (or pointer) to the internal pointer of `unique_ptr`. Could you give a simple implementation of what you have in mind?

Comment: I think [I got it](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Yezar14PM). It's a good idea.

Comment: _directly_ we know that the only instance data in the `unique_ptr` is the underlying pointer, so just `reinterpret_cast`.  Include some `static_assert` to verify that assumption in case you use some special debug version.
_proxy_ you got it.